# can't from module import function but import module ,then module.function is success

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a project, and found previous normal function failure. After debug, it was found that there was a problem with from module. I type `from utils import pub` and execute project, it shows `mportError: cannot import name 'pub'`, but if I type 'import utils' and then utils.pub(), it executes successfully. And my other py file that used the `from module import function` can be used directly

`utils.py`

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe

def pub(topics, payload, mqtt_host, mqtt_port):
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.enable_logger(logger)
    client.connect(mqtt_host, mqtt_port, 60)
    client.loop_start()
    client.publish(topics, payload, 2)
    client.loop_stop()
```

`handle.py`

```
from utils import pub

... some code
```

it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect.py", line 7, in <module>
    from utils import *
  File "utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    from handle import app_handle
  File "handle.py", line 6, in <module>
    from utils import pub
ImportError: cannot import name 'pub'
```

`handle.py`

```
import utils

utils.pub(topic,payload,MQTT_IP,MQTT_PORT)
```

it runs normal

and other `connect.py` that used `from utils import pub` runs normal

Part of the project file structure is as follows

```
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 4 user  user   4096 Sep   4 18:36 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 user  user   4096 Aug   3 17:33 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user  user   3514 Sep   5 09:14 collect.py*
-rw------- 1 user  user   6646 Sep   5 09:56 connect.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user  user   2403 Sep   5 09:46 handle.py*
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep   5 09:46 __pycache__/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user  user  17495 Sep   5 09:15 utils.py
```

Although `import` can be used to solve this problem, I would like to know what causes this problem

Comment: Do you have a circular/mutual dependency? That can cause that problem. It would also explain why it works fine in the other file.

Comment: yes,,,ԾㅂԾ,,There is a circular/mutual dependency in my project. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not a problem. In that case you'll have to keep using the `import foo` syntax.